# Voltage drop on transformer's secondary winding experiment

Tags: transformer

I've read things about it but I couldn't understand it. Let's say I have a 3-phase transformer and voltage of secondary winding is 230. When I keep adding 1k resistors (as load) in paralel it goes like 229V, 228V, 227V... But if I add just inductors or just capacitors in paralel it stays 230V. Why is that?

I may sound really simple but I am really confused. I am not an electrical engineering student by the way.

Comment: To get a better answer you should add _why_ you think the voltage should change with the inductors. Otherwise it's hard to answer on a level that you will understand. Electronics isn't easy.

Comment: @pipe I think may be it is because resistors draw active power and others draw reactive power. But i cant really explain it. Can you give me at least a topic that I should look in to ?

Comment: Nope, but hopefully someone will answer this question. :)

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? A 1k resistor  with 230 volts across it will dissipate over 50 watts. Depending on the design of the transformer, it is not unreasonable for its output voltage to drop with such a large load.  Inductors or capacitors will not dissipate as much power but will draw current.  Depending on their values, however, they may draw less current than the 1k resistor which will keep the voltage from decreasing as much. This is because their reactance may be greater than 1k (it depends on the frequency as well as the capacitance and/or inductance).

Comment: Yes, at 50Hz, you need ~3 microfards of capacitance or 3.3 Henries (an enormous inductance) to get around 1k ohms of reactance (bit like resistance but no energy is used, it just cycles back and forth). if you've used a lower value capacitor or a higher value inductor it'd have less drop. It's also possible that there's some reasonance going on which may be causing some odd behaviour (at resonance, energy tends to build up in the circuit which can raise the voltage - capacitors and inductors don't really burn energy (they just 'hot potato it back and forth) so it keeps building up

Comment: If there ever is a made up bunch of bolony of a question, this has to be likely winner. Everything said or implied about adding 1k resistors (50 watt types) rings untrue. Nobody in their right mind is going to go to this trouble. Next an inductor, usually something like a few mH or microhenry is common enough but to find one that is at least the reactive impedance of 1kohm at 50/60 Hz and start experimenting is just not cutting the mustard as likely. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a made-up bunch of bolony.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the possible likelihoods :

1- The first part of your experiment is acceptable . The resistor draws current from secondary winding and causes voltage drop across the inherent resistance of the winding . By adding resistors in parallel the current increases and consequently you observe more voltage drop .

2- For the second case , in normal cases by connecting an inductor to the output of winding , you should notice a voltage drop . The higher amount of inductor will cause the lower amount of current and thus the lower voltage drop . What you have seen in your experiment is doubtful and doesn't match the principles . Maybe your inductors are damaged and there is no current flowing through them . Or maybe your inductors have high resistance and you need more inductors to be paralleled . You can test your inductors beforehand by a digital multimiter .

3- When you connect capacitor to the secondary winding , there should be a current flowing through it . The higher amount of capacitance will cause a higher amount of current . But its doubtful in your experiment . Maybe your capacitors are very small in amount . Or damaged ones .

When you connect resistor to an AC voltage , the voltage drop is correspond to the level of current , whereas when you connect inductor or capacitor , the voltage drop will not be proportional to current level . However this will not affect the results of your test.